# pstool + pgfplots + parskip conflict

Tags: pgfplots, incompatibility, parskip, psfrag

I've recently observed extremely strange latex bug if `pstool` + `pgfplots` + `parskip` packages are used at the same time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \psfragfig{fig}
    \caption{Figure Psfrag.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code just inserts a psfrag figure, generated by [matlabfrag](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21286-matlabfrag) extension. If these three packages are used, than the resultant output is cropped from below, see figure. However, once I remove `\usepackage{pgfplots}`, the problem is resolved and the output is perfect! Has anyone experienced this issue? Any suggestions how to resolve it?

[image: latex bug]

Comment: Completely sure. In fact, the issue arises even if I modify `\parskip` manually, not necessarily via `\usepackage{parskip}`. So it is somehow related with the non-zero value of the `\parskip`.

Comment: I cannot compile your example (I don't have *that* .eps). May be you should give us something which *we* can compile and which shows the same problem.

Comment: Here is that [eps file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j418aom5mbeggel/fix.zip).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with `latex P && dvips P.dvi -o P.ps` and not with `... && ps2pdf P.ps`. I used the most recent pgfplots/pgf combination and some older one (pgf 2.10 / pgfplots 1.5). Could you give more input about your versions? Furthermore, I would expect that you can substitute `pgfplots` by `tikz` in your example.