# pstool + pgfplots/tikz + parskip conflict resolved

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, incompatibility, parskip, pstool

A while back a question about a [conflict between `pstool`, `pgfplots` and `parskip` packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170969/pstool-pgfplots-parskip-conflict) was asked. I came across a similar problem using the `pstool`, `tikz` and `parskip` packages in concert, and happened to find a solution to it. However, I couldn't post the solution on the original thread, since by then the topic was closed (before it was resolved). [edited from here] I therefore re-posted the the issue as a new question, and on Christian's advice (see comments), my solution is posted below.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is no question then but a solution. You restate the former problem and then add your solution as a self-answer (accepting it, of course)

Comment: You're right, of course. Sorry about that, but I couldn't find any way to answer on the original thread, so I did the next best thing I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own "question".
I resolved this issue by using the `\ifpdf` command, which is mentioned in the pstool package documentation, as follows:

```
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{parskip}
\fi
```

The `\ifpdf` command creates a conditional preamble only for the non-graphics sections. I think that this way, the graphics are not subject to the nonzero `\parskip` that the `parskip` package introduces. I think that it is this nonzero parskip that pushes the graphic down during the `pstool` processing, causing the bottom part to be cropped, which was the original problem.

Hope this helps someone dealing with the same problem.